# Loading jQuery on window.onload?

Tags: javascript, jquery, onload, appendchild

i would like to load jquery.js after the window.onload event has been fired by browser (reducing load time)

Doing that maybe with appendChild the problem is i can't use anymore $(document).ready();

Is there a way to use something equivalent to .ready after the loading of jQuery (after the window.onload?)

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just [place `<script>`s at the bottom of your HTML files](http://developer.yahoo.com/blogs/ydn/posts/2007/07/high_performanc_5/). If you load jQuery right before the closing `</body>` tag, page rendering isn’t blocked while jQuery is loading.

It doesn’t matter if you speed up `window.onload` if you’re not gonna use it anyway. E.g. if you use…

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // …
});
```

…or its shorter alias…

```
$(function() {
  // …
});
```

…internally it’s not relying on `window.onload`, but on `DOMContentLoaded`.

Loading scripts at the bottom is gonna help you much more than waiting for `window.onload` to start loading your scripts.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't. In order to use jquery as well as other plugins that developed from jquery, you have to load jquery.js first of all. (in the  part, you have to put the script that load jquery.js on top)

It doesn't even work if you load (Slider, Thickbox, DatePicker...) first then jquery.js

^^

Comment: i can load the plugin after jquery with appendChild if that's a problem

Answer (score 0):

first of all load jquery from here

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js">

loading it from google means the user most likley already has it cached resulting in a much quicker load.

also to be honest jquery isnt that big a file (less than a meg) so it shouldnt really affect load times.

Comment: I know the standard way to load jquery (i think everyone know) i wanted to know with appendchild

Answer (score 0):

all script tags should be at the bottom of your page in anycase.. so loading times wont be affected.

content

script tags

---

otherwise you could do something like

if ($.jquery){
document.body. and then my js gets rusty... but basicaly append the script tag